# Unix Command to check for missing file in sequence

Tags: unix, awk, sed, cut

Below is file format in a folder.

```
File format - fact_type_<key>_partid
fact_type_123_1
fact_type_123_2
fact_type_123_3
fact_type_123_4
fact_type_124_1
fact_type_124_2
fact_type_124_3
fact_type_124_4
..
fact_type_130_1
```

Each key should have 4 files `(i.e Key1 should have 4 files ending with 1, 2, 3 and 4).`

Keys should be in sequence, for above example next file should be `fact_type_125_1`

Above files are loaded from an external process and the next process will fail if we don't have all the files between start and end key `(4 files for each key and all keys starting 123 till 130)`.

Right now am using cut command and copy the data to excel and then find out any missing keys

```
ls -1a | cut -d '_' -f3 | sort | uniq
```

Please help me with the command to validate this within the folder.

Comment: Are the two numbers 123 and 130 known?

Comment: No, these are unknown, as we have many folders where we have to do this validation. but we can get the start and end value for each folder

Comment: i was testing your previous answer using for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and GNU sort:

```
for f1 in fact_type_*; do
  echo "${f1%_[0-9]}"
done | sort -u |\
while read -r f2; do
  for ((i=1; i<=4; i++)); do
    f="${f2}_${i}"
    [[ ! -e "$f" ]] && echo "missing $f"
  done
done
```

Output (e.g.):

```
missing fact_type_126_4
missing fact_type_127_1
missing fact_type_127_2
missing fact_type_127_4
```

Answer (score 0):

So, constraints:

> Each key should have 4 files
>
> Keys should be in sequence

So I did this:

- First we need to get all files
- then we need the max and min keys
- then we need to generate the sequence from min and max key with each {1..4} suffixes
- then we need to check for each entry if the file exists

The script:

```
check() {
  local keys
  keys=$(
    # find all the files
    find "$1" -regex '.*/fact_type_[0-9]+_[0-4]' \
      -type f -printf "%f\n" |
    # extract the keys
    cut -d_ -f3
  )

  if [ -z "$keys" ]; then
    echo "No files found"
    return 255
  fi

  local nonexisting
  nonexisting=$(
    # sort it
    <<<"$keys" sort |
    # extract first and last key only
    sed -n '1p;$p' |
    # generate sequence
    xargs seq |
    # append {1..4} to all keys
    xargs -i printf "%s\n" "fact_type_{}_"{1..4} |
    # print only nonexisting files
    xargs -l sh -c '[ ! -e "$1" ] && printf "%s\n" "$1"' --
  )

  if [ -n "$nonexisting" ]; then
    <<<"$nonexisting" xargs printf "File %s does not exists\n"
    return "$(<<<"$nonexisting" wc -l)"
  fi
}

touch fact_type_{123..130}_{1..4}

check .  # all ok

rm fact_type_130_1
rm fact_type_125_4
check .  # two files missing
```

will output (the first `check .` outputs nothing, the second only outputs):

```
File fact_type_125_4 does not exists
File fact_type_130_1 does not exists
```

tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/PristineShockedWrapper).

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        fname = ARGV[i]
        split(fname,fparts,/_/)
        key = fparts[3]
        id  = fparts[4]
        ids[key][pid]
    }
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (key in ids) {
        if ( (prevKey != "") && (key != prevKey+1) ) {
            printf "key gap: %s -> %s\n", prevKey, key | "cat>&2"
        }
        prevId = ""
        idCnt = 0
        for (id in ids[key]) {
            if ( (prevId != "") && (id != prevId+1) ) {
                printf "id gap: %s, %s -> %s\n", key, prevId, id | "cat>&2"
            }
            if (id !~ /^[1234]$/) {
                printf "bad id: %s, %s\n", key, id | "cat>&2"
            }
            idCnt++
            prevId = id
        }
        if (idCnt != 4) {
            printf "bad id count: %s, %s\n", key, idCnt | "cat>&2"
        }
        prevKey = key
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk *
```